# How to maintain view (controller) state between route changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a single page application written in AngularJS and using ui-router to manage state transitions (routing).

There is a search state configured like this:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('social.search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'views/social/search/social-search-view.html',
      controller: 'SocialSearchController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
}
```

This view renders a form and the controller (`SocialSearchController`) takes care of getting these inputs, submiting them to a service and displaying the results. The result list is shown to user as a ranked list (like Google's search result page). Each result has a link to go to a new state to show detailed information about the entry, for example:

```
<a ui-sref="social.profile({personId: person.id})">{{person.name}}</a>
```

The `social.profile` state is used in other parts of the application, so it is not a child of `social.search`, it is configured like this:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('social.profile', {
    url: '/{personId}',
    templateUrl: 'views/social/profile/social-profile-view.html',
    controller: 'SocialProfileController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
}
```

It's working fine, I can type my search, get the results and then click to check detailed information about an entry. But, when I hit the back button to transition from the detailed view back to the search view, my inputs and search results are gone. I understand this is the default and correct behavior, as there is no need to keep the controller in memory if it is not used anymore.

The thing is, in this particular scenario, I want the controller to stay in memory somehow, so the user do not need to retype the query and issue another request for the search service.

I can think of saving the search state into a service and make the controller grab its initial state from it, something like a cache service just to store the last controller's state. But then I'm vulnerable to bugs involved in this syncing process, the search form is a bit complicated as it involves auto-complete and tag fields (custom directives I've made) so the syncing will go thru at least three "layers": controller state, cache service, custom inputs.

Is this the correct way to do so? What are my options?

Comment: what about adding another view for your search-results ('/search/{searchString}'). Your form will "submit" to that view, and the back button in the profliel view will work.

Comment: I have more fields than a single search string, but I get your point (to maintain the input state in the route url). This will work for the user to avoid retyping, but it will make a new request for the search service (backend) to repopulate the result list.

Comment: I think it is correct if it makes the request again, (you may have new results to show, for instance), but it probably depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether ui-router is keeping the controllers and datas between parent and childstates, but if this is the case, you could try to "duplicate" your state.

```
function config($stateProvider) {

 var socialProfile = {
    url: '/{personId}',
    templateUrl: 'views/social/profile/social-profile-view.html',
    controller: 'SocialProfileController',
    controllerAs: 'vm' } 

  $stateProvider
    .state('social.search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'views/social/search/social-search-view.html',
      controller: 'SocialSearchController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
    $stateProvider.state("social.search.detail', socialProfile);
    $stateProvider.state('social.profile', socialProfile);  
  }
```

In the 'social.search'-view, you then could just have a special href

```
<a ui-sref="social.search.detail({personId: person.id})">{{person.name}}</a>
```

In this config your socialProfile is a child state of search, but remains a independent state as well

Comment: This seems to work, but I need to add a `ui-view` to the parent state to show the detailed view. In my case, I would like this child `ui-view` to occupy the entire view. Any way to do a `ng-if` or something like this to check if there is a child state?